# what does "-Bbn" means in Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I followed this article [Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#restricting-access) to set up a restricted access docker registry.
I don't understand the following snippet.

```
$ docker run \
  --entrypoint htpasswd \
  registry:2 -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd
```

I checked the docker official [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) document, but I didn't find the `-Bbn` reference.

## Question

What does `-Bbn` means?

Where can I find the document of `-Bbn`?

Comment: The `-Bbn` seems like a combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-Bbn` are the arguments of `htpasswd` command (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html), which is specified in argument

```
--entrypoint htpasswd
```

The `docker run` command essentially runs the command below in the `registry:2` Docker container

```
htpasswd -Bbn testuser testpassword
```

and then redirect the output the file `auth/htpasswd` in your local directory

Update: To run the command `htpasswd -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd` (with redirection) in the container. You can run it as a `/bin/sh` command instead with the redirection included

```
docker run \
  registry:2 /bin/sh -c "htpasswd -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd"
```

If `auth` is not found in the directory, you can create it before running the `htpasswd` command

```
docker run \
  registry:2 /bin/sh -c "mkdir -p auth && htpasswd -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd"
```

Comment: You said: the `htpasswd -Bbn testuser testpassword > auth/htpasswd` will be running inside the `registry:2` image. however, when I get inside the `registry:2` image, I didn't find the `auth/htpasswd` file in the `registry:2` image.

Comment: The `auth/htpasswd` file doesn't exist in the docker `registry:2`, it exists in my local machine instead, could you explain more about this?

Comment: Oh sorry about that. I made a mistake, the redirect operations actually forward the output of the docker run command to the `auth/htpasswd` in your local directory. I've updated my post with an approach to redirect it to a file the container instead

Answer (score 3):

All docker args come *before* the image name; those args are for htpasswd, which is the .. yup, you guessed it, the “entry point”.

The [htpasswd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html) args mean use bcrypt, run in batch, use standard output.